# Formatted date using NSDateFormater & ShortStyle - but aways have full 4 digit year

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

Looking to get a locale-aware formatted date (e.g., 12/31/2014).  But I want to have a full 4-digit year.  NSDateFormatter returns what it thinks is the standard for the locale which sometimes has 2 digits and sometimes 4 digits.

Here's the code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSLog(@"Date for US = %@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
NSLog(@"Date for GB = %@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Results:

```
2014-09-27 22:49:28.875 Play3[17026:60b] Date for US = 9/27/14
2014-09-27 22:49:28.876 Play3[17026:60b] Date for GB = 27/09/2014
```

Comment: Please add it as an edit, not a comment.

Comment: If you want a specific date format do `setDateFormat`.

Comment: If I use setDateFormat it won't be locale-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an internal dicotmony in your question, you want to present a "local-aware formatted date" but you want to change it's representation, i.e. to something your users will not normally see/expect.

Having said that you probably should look at [`NSDateFormatter  dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_3)

Comment: @BobGlass glad to help, when answers are right, please mark them as correct so others can find them easily.

Comment: @cppi.  Just marked it correct.  BTW - Do you know why the question was down-voted.  It seems like a pretty reasonable request - and apparently Apple recognized the need for it - otherwise they wouldn't have provided this routine.

Comment: @BobGlass - no idea, some people are just a-holes.